# Using python / pandas to flatten a data frame and widen it?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a tabular data set which I am trying to flatten down into a wide format.

In the image below, the first table contains a tabular data set for loan information for a client. A client can have multiple loans associated with them.

Is it possible to flatten the first table to be like the second table, where for each unique client ID (first column), any records are appended onto the respective client ID? i.e. for clients 271877 & 108129, for the two records it now becomes a pair of two sets of columns?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a2kM.jpg

The reason I am trying to do this is to join afterwards onto the primary table where I am using this data,